# Accepted answer unaccepted during merge?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196689/how-to-apply-own-template-on-joomla) has been unaccepted (-15 rep's ;-( ). I am wondering if this was because [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) merged that question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876322/custom-template-support-for-joomla) which is not at all an exact duplicate in my mind. And of course to that question my answer is not a good answer at all.

The question which I originally answered was about converting an existing non-Joomla template, the other, and older, about the possibility of having custom templates in Joomla. Where's the line for "exact duplicate"?

Comment: @UristMcBobby look at the bottom of the post; it *was* merged

Comment: @BenBrocka: What the...since when is that possible?! And since when is it done? Anyway, in that case I say that it of course was unaccepted, as it is now on another question owned by someone else (there is no way to force an accepted answer).

Comment: @UristMcBobby It's extremely rare, usually only when someone posts the *exact same* question down to the wording, or someone cross-posts on multiple sites and the cross-posts get migrated to the same site. Only mods can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The older question is asking how to create a custom template that is Joomla supportable.

> Joomla is pretty good CMS but, is there any way to create custom template which will be joomla supportable ?

The newer question asked how to apply an existing template (which was not provided) to Joomla.

> I have my own template which is currently not in the same pattern as that of JOOMLA Template & I want to apply my own template on Joomla.
>
> But I don't know that how I can do it..?

That really lacks the detail required to be answerable.  Your answer was to throw out the existing (not provided) template and start over from a Joomla template, which takes the OP back to the state of the original question.

Maybe both questions should just have been deleted.  They're really not high enough quality (as well as being too old) to migrate to the Joomla site where they belong.  Regardless, I gave you an upvote for being able to extract enough useful information from those questions to provide an acceptable answer.